# View Card is still showing after removing items in card

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce to create on ecommerce website. I am facing one issue on product category page. If removed the items from card. view card is still showing instead of add to card. please refer screenshot.

[image]

I am trying this but its not working

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return $passed;
}
```

if anybody can help me out for this.

Comment: This is a customized cart depending on your theme, so ask the theme authors instead reporting this bug.

Comment: any other alternative way

Comment: As each theme is different, the way to solve a theme bug is to ask authors on their support pages.